# Android - call fragment from a recycler view inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an application (Java) which originally had 5 sections. All of these are fragments and they are accessed by 5 icons in the bottom navigation. However, one of the sections (Lessons) is now being replaced by a different fragment which contains a recycler view. Under this new design, one of the items in the recycler view will call the Lessons fragment.

The question is, how can I call the Lessons fragment from within the Recycler View contained in the new fragment?

Usually inside a recycler view I'd use code like the following:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int index = getAdapterPosition();
        LessonItem item = lessonList.get(index);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("lesson", item);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }
```

but in this case I'm not dealing with an activity. Is there a way I can accomplish this without having to convert the fragment to an activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *ismailfarisi* mentioned before, if you use Navigation Component, it makes the transition easier.

However, if you want to still manage fragment replacements manually, you can **interface**s as callback.

```
interface LessonItemListener {
     void onItemClick(LessonItem item);
}
```

in your recycler view adapter

```
class YourAdapter {

   public YourAdapter(LessonItemListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
   }

   private LessonItemListener listener;

   ...

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        int index = getAdapterPosition();
        LessonItem item = lessonList.get(index);
        listener.onItemClick();
   }

}
```

in your fragment has recyclerview

```
class YourFragment {

     private LessonItemListener listener;

     
     public void setListener(LessonItemListener listener) {
          this.listener = listener;
     }

     private void setupRecyclerView() {
          YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(listener);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

}
```

in your Activity contains those fragments

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LessonItemListener {


    private void setupFragments() {
          YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
          fragment.setListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(LessonItem item) {
         //you are in activity now
         //make whatever you want here
         //such as fragment replacement in your bottom nav
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

navigation component from jetpack is better for handling fragment transition

you can check this documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation